# Assigning multiple snippets to a single key binding

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

In Textmate I have several snippets assigned to specific key equivalents.

So <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> would open a little menu that gave me the choice of some number of snippets.

Is the same thing possible in Sublime Text 2?

Follow-uo:
In Textmate you assign key equivalents to a snippet and you can assign the same key equ. to multiple snippets.  When there is more than one snippet for a selected key equ. a menu opens with all of the snippets assgned to that key equ on it.

This really helps me out...I can have a number of PHP snippets on <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, a bunch of jQuery snippets on <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> etc... and I don't have to remember a crazy number of key equ, just one for PHP stuff, etc...

Comment: sorry, don't quite follow. Do you want a menu to appear with all snippets in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this line:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+f1"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette", "text": "snippet"} }
```

to your keybindings file `/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap`. Then everytime you press `shift+f1`. A popup menu will appear with all snippets. But you only want some snippets. So... in you snippet files that you want to appear add the line:

```
<description>php snippet, some description</description>
```

And change the line in the top keybinding from `"text": "snippet"` in the to `"text": "php snippet"`. Now when you hit `shift+f1` all snippets with description beginning with `php snippet` will appear, with their full descriptions. And you can repeat this process for all your different groups.

Comment: Any idea as to how ST2 determines what order to put those snippets in the menu?  (I'd love to be able to reorder them)

Comment: @Jason - hmm, wierd. I don't see much of a pattern or order to it. my guess is ordered by scope, then alphanumeric on file name, but i don't have time to check it out properly right now...

Comment: File name or description does not seem to have any effect on order.  FYI: I've asked this as a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182708/ordering-the-items-in-the-command-palette-overlay-in-sublime-text-2