# Ordering the items in the command palette overlay in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

With the help from [fraxel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175101/fraxel) on this question: [Assigning multiple snippets to a single key binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043695/assigning-multiple-snippets-to-a-single-key-binding) I was able to create a handy popup menu to organize all my snippets in the way Textmate works.

Is it possible to tell ST2 what order I want them to appear in in the overlay command palette?  Right now they are seemingly random and I'd love to be able to set some order to them.

I can't tell how ST2 orders them.

**More**:

All of my snippets have file names that indicate their language:
e.g.

- PHP_mySQLLoop.sublime-snippet
- PHP_mySQLi.sublime-snippet
- HTML_basePage.sublime-snippet
- jQuery_ajax.sublime-snippet

The `<description>` I use is also standard:

- JMR PHP, mySQL Loop
- JMR PHP, mySQLi
- JMR HTML, Base page
- JMR jQuery, $ajax

Changing PHP_mySQLi.sublime-snippet to PHP_1_mySQLi.sublime-snippet or 1_PHP_mySQLi.sublime-snippet had no effect nor did changing it's description.

I do not have the `<scope>` set for any snippet at his point...maybe I should...?
(This is on OS X, not sure if that has anything to do with this...)

Comment: Also interested in that question. I want my custom snippet to be above the default ones, makes sense...

Comment: Anyone found a solution to this yet? There's a command I type in the Command Palette probably a hundred times a day, and if I could type less characters for it to show up as the top suggestion, it'd be really nice.